# Cleaning up selected characters from a column

Tags: excel, string, vba

this macro should clean up some special characters. When I run it it wipes out everything. I start testing this with only one column "B".
May you please help figuring out where is the error?. 
I've posted a similar question in regards to regular expressions, hence this might be procedural approach to what I've been trying to achieve, which is to standardize data to export all of this to a SQL Database.
Please note in the comments that this macro mostly cleans up data entered by user.

Thanks once more for your comments/answers/suggestions.

```
Sub CaracteresEspeciales()

'Esta macro es una version extendida que toma caracteres predefinidos de una lista
MsgBox "Esta macro encuentra caracteres especiales más usados, se tomará unos breves instantes"

Worksheets("Candidatos").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim asterisco As String
Dim coma As String
Dim punto As String
Dim dospuntos As String
Dim puntoycoma As String
Dim slash As String
Dim backslash As String
Dim chevron As String
Dim apostrofe As String
Dim leftparenthesis As String
Dim righparenthesis As String
Dim porcentaje As String
Dim ampersand As String
Dim dollarsign As String
Dim leftquestionmark As String
Dim rightquestionmark As String
Dim leftexclamationmark As String
Dim rightexclamationmark As String
Dim backtilde As String
Dim tilde As String
Dim arroba As String
Dim espacio As String


asterisco = "*"
coma = ","
punto = "."
dospuntos = ":"
puntoycoma = ";"
slash = "/"
backslash = "\"
chevron = "`"
apostrofe = "'"
leftparenthesis = "("
rightparenthesis = ")"
porcentaje = "%"
ampersand = "&"
dollarsign = "$"
leftquestionmark = "¿"
rightquestionmark = "?"
leftexclamationmark = "¡"
rightexclamationmark = "!"
backtilde = "`"
tilde = "´"
arroba = "@"
espacio = " "


Worksheets("Candidatos").Activate

Columns("B:B").Replace What:=coma, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=punto, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=dospuntos, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=puntoycoma, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=slash, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=backslash, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=chevron, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=apostrofe, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=leftparenthesis, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=righparenthesis, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=porcentaje, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=ampersand, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=dollarsign, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=leftquestionmark, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=rightquestionmark, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=leftexclamationmark, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=rightexclamationmark, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=backtilde, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=tilde, replacement:=espacio
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=arroba, replacement:=espacio



Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'what type of data (in spanish)
'personales (b,c,k)  personal data
'laborales (q, u ,z), (ab, af, ak) ,( am, aq, av) , (ax,bb,bg) work desc.
'estudiantiles (bi,bj),(bq,br),(by,bz),(cg,ch) academic info.




MsgBox "Gracias por la espera, se han limpiado datos personales"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that `asterisco` is being interpreted as a wildcard?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, with this method, has to do with wild cards.  `*` and `?` are both wild cards and will match either a single character or, **all** the characters.

To interpret as a literal, change your `What` strings to `~*` and `~?`

```
asterisco = "~*"
rightquestionmark = "~?"
```

If you are also including `~` as a character to be replaced (I didn't see it), then it should be entered as `~~`

Comment: Just for clarification - the `?` matches all single characters, the `*` matches all strings, correct?

Comment: @dwirony That is correct.  However, if you do a `Range.Find` with a partial match and use the `?` for the `What` argument, it will still replace every single character (i.e. the entire string) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, fact I've now corrected the wildcards, and it works OK. Some characters like the right parenthesis won't get removed yet, so I,m checking for any further errors.
 Should there be a way to enumerate all columns as an array, in order to update all the list of them with these changes?.

Comment: and just noticed that I have some typos, that was why some commands did not work properly. tks again

Comment: @lbhsdc You can catch most of the typos by placing `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your macro.  In addition, you should change the default option under `Tools - Options - General - Editor` to **require** `variable declaration`.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of every new module, and is good practice.

Comment: @lbhsdc Since my answer seems to have helped, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the Answer (check box near upper left)

Comment: Thanks Again! certainly it helped a lot. Cheers